# Edit RTF/DOC file programmatically in xcode/ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a RTF file which I can view on iphone , Now I need to edit the file programmatically , please let me know how can I do it.
Example
RTF file content
"I am new to StackOverflow"
Now I need to change to below line programmatically.
"I regularly visit StackOverflow" and save as PDF file.
Please do help me :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can not write the file in the iphone . its work in simullator work because it has a permission to write . but in iphone or ipad it not give the permission to write the file . you must have to use for the database .

Comment: Hi Parag,Thanks for the info, but there must be some way where I can set the permission of the file and then edit the file , so plz let me know if there are any references/code , thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .h file add some objects and defines

```
#define kBorderInset            20.0
#define kBorderWidth            1.0
#define kMarginInset            10.0

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CGSize pageSize;
    NSString *pdfFileName;
    NSString *contents_for_pdf;
}

- (void)generatePdfWithFilePath:(NSString *)thefilePath;
```

in .m file add this lines some where on button click to get contents of rtf file in string

```
NSString *rtf_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"rtf"];
contents_for_pdf = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:rtf_path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",contents_for_pdf);
contents_for_pdf = [contents_for_pdf stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"I am new to StackOverflow" withString:@"I regularly visit StackOverflow"];

pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
```

I didnt modify the text of rtf file,I just used same text in rtf file.you should do as you want(I noticed some encoding characters in text) and function that will generate pdf is here.

```
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);
    //Start a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    //Draw text fo our header.

    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [contents_for_pdf sizeWithFont:font
                                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [contents_for_pdf drawInRect:renderingRect 
                        withFont:font
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                       alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PDF Created" message:@"Sucessfull" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [Alert show];
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the code and this code is to create a PDF file :) but my main concern is about edit the rtf file or the doc file, so there must be some way where I can edit the RTF/DOC file programmatically.Pls let me know the reference if you have

Comment: You asked in question for saving as PDF file. And you want to change that word then after having contents of rtf make a string search and replace words in string and write it to PDF file as you asked in question.

Comment: Yup for are correct but your code shows how to create a pdf file ,  but I need to change the contents and then create , like from your code after NSLog(@"%@",contents_for_pdf); I want to change the contents and then create PDF file , so please help in that,So basically I am not able to make changes in the contents_for_pdf , when I try to make changes its not reflecting :(

Comment: @user1450901,I edited the answer, check the line after NSLog(@"%@",contents_for_pdf);

Comment: Hi I did used the code , but if the RTF file when displayed it will be clear but when taken its contents then it will be in some other format , same when converting to pdf its in some other format . Example RTF file : Hello How are you, now its contents from [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:rtf_path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; will be hello /n how /n are /n etc. now when converted to PDF then again its content will be hello /n how /n are , but I want to be exactly same as RTF contents like How are you ,  thanks for your help

Comment: @IamAnil you can try contents_for_pdf = [contents_for_pdf stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""]; before generating pdf.And I already mentioned in answer that I noticed encoding characters in generated pdf. And I don't have an idea to remove those characters you can try your luck in contents_for_pdf = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:rtf_path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; by changing encoding.

Comment: Solved the issue by converting the RTF to image then to PDF. :)

Comment: dont convert the rtf to image and then to pdf man .. the generated pdf after such a procedure will not support text parsing. What i mean is, that in the generated PDF, you won't be able to search for words. To replace `\n` as such use `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc` method

Comment: i am getting following string in webview when i load pdf file in ios {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red254\green209\blue100;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;\csgray\c100000;\csgenericrgb\c99608\c81961\c39216;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0
\f0\i\b\fs72 \cf2 \ul \ulc2 acc} instead of a string acc can u please help me out how to convert rtf to pdf