# How to edit an existing pdf document in an iOS application using any third party libraries.

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I would like to edit an existing pdf document,most probably comes from the server. My requirement is to edit the pdf document. Here editing means i want to add some text at some particular place. Whenever user clicks on a document at some place where he wishes to enter the text, keyboard should appear and can able to write some text. In the same way, he should be able to delete some of the text which he doesn't want to use in the existing document. After all these manipulations he should be able to save the document. I have been trying with fastpdfkit framework, everything is possible but entering text and deleting is not working which is the main requirement for me. Anybody who had worked with this kind of requirement could probably help me.

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419262/how-to-get-contents-or-index-of-the-pdf/17419442#17419442

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [fastpdfkit](http://fastpdfkit.com/).

Download the sample code form [github](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit) and make use of it.

Comment: i tried with fastpdfkit but it is not supporting the text entering. It is supporting rest of the things like highlighting the text, bookmarking @nazik

Comment: @iosdevelpr, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994432/edit-rtf-doc-file-programmatically-in-xcode-ios) may give you an idea

Comment: thanks for the response but i dont want some static text to be inserted in the document.I want the user to type text when clicked on some position on the document

Answer (score 0):

Try following demo of [Leaves framework](https://github.com/brow/leaves)

Comment: i think it is not supporting interactive files. i need pdf files to be interactive.